# 2d array permutation proof

Tags: math

I want to know if it's possible to get any possible combination of a 4x4 integer array given three rules:

- you may shift any column up or down
- you may shift any row left or right
- you may shift the entire array left, right, up, or down

That is, you can transform:

```
[1]  [2]  [3]  [4]
[5]  [6]  [7]  [8]
[9]  [10] [11] [12]
[13] [14] [15] [16]
```

into any possible combination of a 4x4 array of the same 16 values, given those three rules.

Basically, I just want to know if there are impossible combinations.

Comment: Your third "rule" is redundant, because it can be accomplished via sequences of the first two...

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it may be useful. By brute force analysis, I found that a 3x3 array can be transformed into 181,440 different states using your rules. That's exactly half the number of total possible states a 3x3 array can have, 9! = 362,880.

Comment: But brute forcing a 2x4 array, I can reach all 8! states. Hmm. Maybe arrays with an even number of elements are solvable, and arrays with an odd number of elements aren't?

Comment: No, that can't be it, because 1xN arrays aren't solvable for any N greater than 2.

Comment: This is more of a math question than a CS question - it boils down to whether the group structure can generate all permutations.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a math/group theory problem, which is more appropriate at math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operations are sufficient to reach every possible combination.
To prove it we only need to demonstrate that there's a sequence of operations that swap `[1]` and `[2]` and leave the remaining elements in their original positions, since by the symmetry of your operations we can similarly swap any horizontally or vertically adjacent pair of elements and can recursively march through the elements to swap any pair of them.

Defining L as shifting the first row one step left and R as shifting it one step right, and U as shifting the first column one step up and D as shifting it one step down, the sequence of operations LURDLUR yields

```
[2]  [1]  [3]  [4]
[9]  [6]  [7]  [8]
[13] [10] [11] [12]
[5]  [14] [15] [16]
```

This swaps the elements `[1]` and `[2]` and rotates the elements `[5]`, `[9]` and `[13]` up. Repeating the sequence twice more will return the latter to their original positions whilst leaving `[1]` and `[2]` swapped and hence we can repeatedly swap elements to get to any possible combination.
Nice puzzle BTW :-)

Comment: This is really cool. Unfortunately, it's impossible to reach every combination in an NxM array where N and M are both odd, since swapping 1 and 2 is an odd permutation and a shifting a row or column on a 3x3 grid, for example, is an even permutation.

Comment: @FGM: Yep. I wrote up an analysis of the 3x3 case a [few](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1538) [years](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1551) ago.